# Getting financial report data from API

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to track financial report data by using  API of https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

My idea is to track all types of data (income statement, balance sheet, and cash flow report) then export them to just one sheet of CSV file at one time.

However, the problem is when I run the code below, its just work with a limited number of tickers
For example: it works if the ticker was `["AMZN", "AAPL"]` but does not work when I add more tickers like `["AMZN", "AAPL", "MSFT"]`

The error message was

> AnualReport_Data = SourceData['annualReports'][:4] KeyError: 'annualReports'

I am using Python.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests

Ticker = ["AMZN", "AAPL", "MSFT"]
# "AAPL", "BABA", "FB", "MSFT"
API_key = "********"
R_elements = ["INCOME_STATEMENT", "BALANCE_SHEET", "CASH_FLOW"]

ReportData = pd.DataFrame()

for stock in Ticker:
    df = []
    for i in range(0, 3):
        API_url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function={R_elements[i]}&symbol={stock}&apikey={API_key}'
        SourceData = requests.get(API_url).json()
        AnualReport_Data = SourceData['annualReports'][:4]
        dfi = pd.DataFrame(AnualReport_Data).set_index('fiscalDateEnding')
        df = dfi.merge(dfi, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        df['company'] = stock
        time.sleep(10)
    df.T.to_dict()
    ReportData = pd.concat([ReportData, df], ignore_index=True)
ReportData.to_csv('AnualReportData.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to ensure that ```SourceData``` has ```annualReports``` as a key.  Right after you use ```requests.get(API_url).json()```, print out what ```SourceData``` is.

Comment: The probable reason, that the API limits 5 api calls per minute, and thereafter sends a response with key 'Note' and value 
'Thank you for using Alpha Vantage! Our standard API call frequency is 5 calls per minute and 500 calls per day. Please visit https://www.alphavantage.co/premium/ if you would like to target a higher API call frequency.'

Comment: Thanks for your advice! it seems the call frequency was limited. I increase the time of sleep to 20 seconds and it worked smoothly